# How do I correctly estimate the size of a subpopulation using noisy observations?

Tags: error, estimators, measurement-error

To preface this question: please comment on whether my description of the problem is missing details or the problem itself is not well-posed as I'm seeing a lot of views but no activity.

I am trying to estimate the size of a subpopulation $c$ where the members of the population are participants of athletic events. This is a subpopulation because our database contains a fraction of all possible athletic events, thus a fraction of all participants. The distribution can be found at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0zb.png).

The subpopulation is associated $N=5027$ athletic events, the records of which were acquired through inbound (events requesting to be added to the database) and outbound (scraped from the web) sources. Each event record $E$ is associated with a number of attributes including participant count, location, website, and event type.

I could clearly take $c = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ParticipantCount(E_{i})$ to be the total number of participants in the subpopulation but the accuracy of the counts are unknown so I need an estimate, $\hat{c}$. I would like to design an observational study to estimate $\hat{c}$ and a $(1-{\alpha})100\%$ confidence interval. Since its infeasible for our team to manually validate the counts of all $N$ events to get the true $c_{i}$s, I plan on taking an unequal probability sample of size $m$ (at least $m=100$) to validate since larger events will contribute more to $c$ than smaller events.

**How do I build a model of $\hat{c}$ and its confidence interval from the sample?**

My proposed approach is to:

1. Manually validate and adjust outliers selected through manual analysis (top 0.01% of the subpopulation) that account for 30% of the estimated subpopulation size so that their error is 0, in order to simplify the sample design.
2. Construct a sampling distribution of the percentage error $e = \frac{(\hat{c} - c)}{c}$ using bootstrap samples of size $m$, from the manually validated sample.
3. Estimate the $(1-{\alpha})100\%$ confidence interval and the mean $\hat{\mu_{e}}$ from the sampling distribution.
4. Use the upper $u$ and lower $l$ bounds of the confidence interval to report the estimate as $\hat{c}_{l} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ParticipantCount(E_{i}) - u$ and $\hat{c}_{u} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ParticipantCount(E_{i}) + abs(l)$.

Assuming this approach is correct, I am still unsure of how to estimate the confidence interval if the resulting distribution from #2 is nonparametric.

**Any feedback on this approach or general guidance would be most appreciated!**

[[1] Participant Count Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0zb.png)